# Android: Google Analytics as part of Google Play Service

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-play-services

Now that Google Analytics will become part of the Google Play Services 4.3, which changes do we need to expect?

do we still need to include the GoogleAnalytics jar into the Android project?

what about dispatching the data? on this page https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/dispatch it's written:

> The local dispatch methods referenced in this document have been
>   marked as deprecated due to the forthcoming availability of Google
>   Analytics as part of Google Play Services. Local dispatch methods may
>   still be used in non-Google-experience devices.

but it doesn't explain how dispatching can be managed under the Google Play Services

also, I wonder, is there the risk that some users won't have Google Play Services 4.3 installed, and so can't be tracked by Google Analytics?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation for Google Analytics SDK v4 (now part of Google Play Services) has just been published!

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/

Answer (score 3):

> do we still need to include the GoogleAnalytics jar into the Android
>   project?

When it's part of Google Play Services, you'll import Google Play Services's library instead.

> but it doesn't explain how dispatching can be managed under the Google
>   Play Services

I think it just means that Google Play Services will make sure the reports will be delivered before the cut-off time, and that we shouldn't need to worry about implementation details.

> also, I wonder, is there the risk that some users won't have Google
>   Play Services 4.3 installed, and so can't be tracked by Google
>   Analytics?

Google Play Services is automatically updated in the background, so virtually all devices with Google
 Play Services installed should be updated (usually the roll-out takes about a few weeks) for 2.3+ devices.

If you worry about those users, or want to Analytics for non-Google devices like Kindle, you can still integrate the standalone library instead.

Comment: Kai, thanks for replying! My new app targets API 14, so users are 4.x and they should all be covered by Google Play Services.

Comment: According to here: http://www.androidcentral.com/google-play-services-43-now-rolling-out-new-apis-support-latest-play-games-improvements: "Google Play Services updates take some time to roll out, but if you download an app or update an app that needs any of the new APIs, it should force the latest Play Services to download." Does it mean we can already use the new Google Play Services version in the dependencies block in Gradle? Is it safe to do so? are the Analytics APIs exactly the same? in case, which line we should we insert exactly? compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.3.+'?

Comment: answering myself :-) obviously the Google Analytics under Google Play Service will have a different package name, which at the moment doesn't appear on the official list: http://developer.android.com/reference/gms-packages.html. Any idea when Google Analytics will officially become available on Google Play Services?

Comment: @DanieleB I think it would be something along the line of `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.3.0'` but I am not 100% certain. For instructions on how to handle cases where the user doesn't have 4.3 installed see here: http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html Also I have just checked Android SDK Manager, it looks like Google Play lib has not been updated yet, you prob can't really release a working version until they've updated the library.